# RiTa.js kwic() white spaces and special characters messed up

Tags: p5.js

I am using RiTa.js library (kwic() function) to look for keywords in a collection of texts and grab the keywords in context.
I am grabbing the words correctly, but when I get the results of kwic model and the sentence has 2 or more special characters together, the white spaces and special characters are messed up.
Can you help me with this? Sorry, I'm super new to p5.js 
Thank you!

```
txt = [];
files = ['Antonopoulou.txt',
  'Barriere.txt',
  'Costa.txt',
  // …
];

function preload() { //load files
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    txt[i] = loadStrings('data/' + files[i]);
  }
  myFont = loadFont('data/FranklinGothicMedium.ttf');
}

function setup() {

  allwords = [];  
  titles = [];    
  authors = [];   

  for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
    allwords[i] = txt.join('\n');                
  }

  counts = RiTa.concordance(allwords.join('\n'));    
  total = totalValues(counts);

  params = {
    ignoreStopWords: false,
    ignoreCase: false,
    ignorePunctuation: false,
    wordCount: 20
  };

  words = [];
  keys = []; 

  for (var k in counts) {       
    if (counts.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      if (counts[k] >= 100) {  
        var tags = RiTa.getPosTags(k);
        if (tags[0] == 'jj') {  
          words.push(k);        
          keys.push(counts[k]); 
        }
      }
    }
  }

  search = [];     
  kwic = [];       

  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {  
    word = words[i];
    key = keys[i];
    result = RiTa.kwic(allwords[i], word, params);  // HERE

    search.push({
      word: word,
      key: key,
      result: result,        
    });

    for (var j = 0; j < search[i].result.length; j++) {
      keyword = search[i].word;
      entry = search[i].result[j];

      kwic.push({
        keyword: keyword,
        entry: entry,
      });

    }
  } 
}
```

The problem seems to be here:

```
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {  
        word = words[i];
        key = keys[i];
        result = RiTa.kwic(allwords[i], word, params);  // HERE

        search.push({
          word: word,
          key: key,
          result: result,        
        });
```

The result has the weird spaces.

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]? Just hard-code a single input and show its output. Right now we can't run your code because we don't have any of the files you're using. Create a simple program that just prints the output to the console so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your reply. Here is the code: https://github.com/catarinalee/prev-next/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your code in sketch.js, but here is a cleaned up version (which doesn't appear to have the problem you describe):

```js
var txt = [];

function preload() {

  var files = ['Lee.txt','Orsi.txt'];
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    txt[i] = loadStrings('data/' + files[i]);
  }
}

function setup() {

  createCanvas(600, 600);

  var alltext = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
    alltext += txt[i].join('\n');
  }

  var lines = RiTa.kwic(alltext, "audio-visual", {
    ignoreStopWords: false,
    ignoreCase: false,
    ignorePunctuation: false,
    wordCount: 5
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    text(i + ") "+lines[i], 20, 20 + i * 20);
  }
}
```

OUTPUT:

[image: sketch output]